# Dynamic declaration of variable in SQL Server Analysis Services MDX query?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

Is there a way to write such a query where we can declare the variable dynamically ?

Currently I am using the query as shown below :

```
declare @pYear_Internal as NVarchar(100)

set @pYear_Internal = [D FISCALPERIOD].[FP CODE].[FP CODE]

WITH

MEMBER MEASURES.[REVENUE] AS [Measures].[TOTAL REVENUE]

SET LAST5YEARS AS STRTOMEMBER(@pYear_Internal).Lag(4) : 

STRTOMEMBER(@pYear_Internal)

SELECT 
{

[MEASURES].[REVENUE]

}

ON COLUMNS,

EXCEPT(LAST5YEARS,[D FISCALPERIOD].[COMP_FP].&[-1].&[-1])

ON ROWS

FROM 

( 

SELECT STRTOMEMBER(@pYear_Internal).PARENT ON 0

FROM [Quadrigence]

)
```

While executing the above query, getting the error -

```
Query (1, 9) Parser: The syntax for '@pYear_Internal' is incorrect.
```

It looks like it doesn't recognize DECLARE keyword as it does with SQL queries.  I just want a query that runs directly against the server.

Please help me out where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Why do want to declare a variable in the script? Are you feeding this script to some report's dataset or want to make a stored proc out of it?

Answer (score 0):

The way we handle this requirement is to construct a dynamic MDX string variable and execute it using OPENQUERY:

```
DECLARE @pYear_Internal varchar(31)='SomeValue';
DECLARE @MDX varchar(max)='    
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''
SELECT STRTOMEMBER('+@pYear_Internal+').PARENT ON 0
FROM [Quadrigence]
'')';
EXECUTE(@MDX);
```

Where MyLinkedServer, of course, is a linked server to your SSAS Server.   So this whole query has to be executed on a SQL Server that can link to your SSAS server.